# Why does not the parameter passed to the keyword argument end in the print function of Python does not work as expected in the below context?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, printing, file-io

I ran the following code,

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       print(line, end=' ')
```

I expected to get,

```
This is the first line This is the second line This is the third line
```

as output.

Instead I got,

```
This is the first line
 This is the second line
 This is the third line
```

Can someone tell me why this behavior occurs?

The content in the .txt file is as below,

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
```

Comment: `end = ' '`You add a space at the end of your print. So your script reads the line, which ends with a \n, and adds a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file you have a line break for each line. You can remove it with the strip() function.

Example:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
     for line in f:
             print(line.strip(), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the text file has a \n after every line so i suggest that you replace the '\n' by '' by adding the following line:

```
line = line.replace('\n', '')
```

So the code would look like this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
   line = line.replace('\n', '')
   print(line, end=' ')
```